# PHP Word image issues

Tags: php, ms-word

Please I am having issues displaying images on the MS-Word document I create dynamically from my php script; I have seen similar questions on SO, sadly they do not solve my problem. Am relatively new to using headers. Please heeeelp! :(

Heres some code to help you guys out:

```
$image64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents('res/myLogo.png'));


header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=document_name.doc");

echo "<html>";
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;charset=Windows1252\">";
echo "<body>";
echo "<b>My Document Header</b>";
echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.$image64.'">';
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
```

The image displays and works fine when I echo it out to a html page, however when the document downloads, the image is not displayed. 
Thanks ahead.

Comment: Cant work out what that code is supposed to do

Comment: Sorry bout that, let me explain briefly - first i convert the image to a base64, then i set the headers, and then echo out the image; thus the MS-Word document will be downloaded to my computer.

Comment: That will nevef work. If yoreare converting from html your souce needs tk be a file on the server

Comment: Any suggestions? I have really been tearing my hair out because of this

Comment: Chage the src to a local file

Comment: Nope. That aint work either. Thanks for the suggestion nonetheless. I'll update here if i find a solution.

Comment: need more details than that if you want my help

Comment: Dagon, see edit. I have put the full code version.